# How can i look up where Constants are defined using Aptana

Tags: php

I am currently working on a shopping cart using an open source PHP framework. it is quite large. i recently installed a plugin that included over 160 separate files!, there is now some kind of logic error going on.

My question is, in using Aptana Studio how i can do the following?

find where a constant is being defined?
find where a function is defined?
is there any way to track variables?

thanks for any help or advice on this

Answer (score 0):

Press `Ctrl + H`. It will let you search, **find**, and replace text among workspace ,files, and projects.

Update: For MAC, `Cmd + Option + G`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the files are linked, you may be able CTRL+click the name of the function / constant / variable to jump to the definition.